# How to Allow Multiple Users to Share One Machine for their Windows Desktops?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, thin, multiple-instances

What's the best way to allow 5 remote users to share one computer for their multiple desktops?

Will any non-server version of windows allow this?

Are there any server versions that will allow this without purchasing additional licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood properly what you mean, the answer is NO, you will need to create a server, then use the Windows Remote Connection on those 5 multiple desktops to cinnect to the server computer. Good luck, you will need it! ;)

Comment: So you will need Windows Server for this.